# Connecting two tables through a auto-generated primary key in Access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access-2013

I am attempting to create a relationship between two tables in Access 2013. The PROJ table has many fields, with the primary key being PID, which is a randomly generated auto_increment number. I would like to use this as the foreign key for another table (JDD) to create a link between them. The primary key for JDD is another non-randomly generated id, UII, and I want the the PROJ table to autopopulate the PIDs into the JDD table. However, logically, I would assume that since it is a randomly generated number that there is no way to connect them and have them auto-populate unless I manually attached the PID to each UII. Is there anyway around this? Access would let me create the relationship but I couldn't find the plus signs to auto-populate data in the Datasheet view.

Thanks!

Comment: I guess I am a little confused.  You would like to set up a foreign key relationship between PROJ and JDD using the int identity column of PROJ, correct?  This requires that either 1) insert records into JDD with the int key reference to PROJ or 2) set up an intermediate table to store the relation between the int id in PROJ and the UII id in JDD.

Comment: Foreign keys should not be autonumbers. Store PID in JDD table as a regular number. Then link the two tables by PID. Use an [AfterInsert data macro](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Ff196099.aspx) to auto populate or use a subform.